# Seeking tool for solving matrices using Cramer's rule

Tags: matrices, soft-question

Summation formulas of any degree can be found using Pascal's triangle and Cramer's rule. For example

\begin{align*}
S_2&=\sum_{x=1}^n x^2= \dfrac{n}{1}
\cdot \dfrac{(n+1)}{2}
\cdot \dfrac{(n+2)}{3}
\end{align*}

In the $\,3x3\,$ matrix below, the columns represent $\,x^3, x^2, x^1\,$ of a set of simultaneous equations and the $\,1x3\,$ matrix is the right hand side of those equations.

$
\begin{bmatrix}
3&0&0\\
3&2&0\\
1&1&1
\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}
1\\2\\1
\end{bmatrix}
$

It is simple, if tedious, to use Cramer's rule on these in a spreadsheet. I'm looking for something simpler than copy pasting the RHS into a LHS column before I take the determinant to obtain each term's numerator. Is there a software tool that can solve these matrices semi-automatically?

$\textbf{Update: }$ A comment suggested Julia. I have Julia and I figured out how to enter a matrix A and a matrix B but how to I get Julia to equate and solve them?

Comment: Perhaps you may check **GeoGebra** – it is **free** interactive mathematics software solution (for learning and teaching science, technology, engineering, and mathematics from primary school up to the university level).

Comment: @Anton Vrdoljak
  I have GeoGegra and I use it for drawing and typesetting minor math expressions but I did not know it could "solve" systems of equations. Wolfram might be able to do it but the source is too long.

Comment: With GeoGebra you are able to do a lot of math. This will result with a matrix: $A=\{\{1,0,0\},\{0,1,0\},\{0,0,1\}\}$. Did you ever used sliders? Try to add 9 sliders, let say $a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,k$, then create a matrix which elements you will control with your sliders. All you have to input is this: $A=\{\{a,b,c\},\{d,e,f\},\{g,h,k\}\}$.

Comment: @Anton Vrdoljak How would I get the solutions to this particular system of equations using GeoGebra? Would it give me the coefficients of $\,x^2,\,x^1,\,x^0$?

Comment: @Anton Vrdoljak  I tried putting the matrices in GeoGebra and it typeset them but how do I solve the set of equations?

Comment: Input matrix $A$ as $A=\{\{3,0,0\},\{3,2,0\},\{1,1,1\}\}$, and matrix $B$ as $B=\{\{1\},\{2\},\{1\}\}$, then the solution you will get wit this input $X=Invert(A)*B$.

Comment: @Anton Vrdoljak I was unable to make your technique work, even with the several-hundred-page GeoGebra manual. I saw no method of solving simultaneous equations with or without matrices. Thanks anyway.

Comment: The `linalg` subpackage in `numpy` can handle this. In fact, if you have a triangular system, this is easy to solve in any language.

Comment: @Sean Roberson None of the matrices will triangular. All of the nxn matrices will have a diagonal of integers descending to 1. All of the 1xn matrices will correspond to row $\,n\,$  of pascal's triangle.